# R: create sequence of unequal spacing

Tags: r, indexing, sequence, spacing

i have a vector where the same word "amount" appears at various intervals:

"amount"    "selection" "rating"    "amount"    "selection"  "amount" "selection"   "selection" "rating" "selection"   "amount"    "selection" "rating"

so in the example above "amount" appears in positions 1, 4, 6, and 11.

I would like to create a sequence that would increment by 1 each time this word is encountered, so that i get a sequence like this:
1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4

any idea how i could do this...?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You could try `cumsum` on the logical vector (`v1=='amount'`)

```
cumsum(v1=='amount')
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("amount", "selection", "rating", "amount", "selection",
"amount" ,"selection" ,"selection", "rating" ,"selection" ,
"amount" ,"selection", "rating")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `ifelse` as a test and `cumsum` on the results of that test.

```
library("magrittr")                                           # for %>% 

v1 <- 
c("amount", "selection", "rating", "amount", "selection",
  "amount", "selection", "selection", "rating", "selection", 
  "amount","selection", "rating")

ifelse(v1 %in% "amount", 1, 0) %>% cumsum
```

Comment: I think this also works  `(v1 =='amount') %>% cumsum`